# Distribute static/dynamic library to Linux via .deb

Tags: linux, debian, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I have created a static and dynamic library that I want to distribute. How should I make my .deb file so the headers are put in /usr/include/, the libraries in /usr/lib/, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two good resources for creating deb packages:

http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/
http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/column/libpkg-guide/libpkg-guide.html

I usually get the source for an existing package (e.g. libgif-dev) and look in the debian directory for code to reuse